# See resolutions and supported refresh rate of connected screen

Tags: display

Is it possible to select a specific resolution and refresh rate on os x el capitan? I attached a screenshot of paying software which gives you the possibility to do this

[image: Possible screen resolutions and supported framerate]

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

For your main display you would:

1. Click on the Apple menu
2. Select System Preferences
3. Select Displays
4. Click on Display
5. Select Scaled to select your resolution

**Notes:**

- If you have more than one display, you can select from additional resolution options by also pressing the <kbd>Option</kbd> key at Step 5.
- You'll also see the refresh rate option after Step 4.

If I've misunderstood your question please let me know.

Comment: Note bullet 1 doesn't work for me. It shows 'larger text' 'default' and 'more space' but says nothing about refresh rate

Comment: see http://i.imgur.com/sVLLyzF.png I'm using a MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Late 2013)

Comment: The screenshot in your question is for an external display, while the screenshot in your comment is for the built in display, so you're not comparing the same thing. If you look at the settings for the external display you'll see the various resolutions and a drop-down menu for the refresh rate. You may find [this page](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH22160) helpful.

Comment: same here - nothing about refresh rate.